# Get a PEM file for a trusted root certificate included in iOS (for authenticating gRPC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ssl, grpc

I have an iOS app that communicates with a server using gRPC. In order to secure the connection, the server has issued a certificate bound to a hostname. I need to validate that certificate against a root certificate on the iOS device.

It looks like the following method, provided by gRPC on iOS, can be used to do the validation:

```
open class func setTLSPEMRootCerts(_ pemRootCert: String?, forHost host: String) throws
```

So to use it, I need to provide the root certificate I want to use for the validation, and the host that the server has issued their certificate against. The host part is easy -- it should just be the hostname that the server-issued cert it bound to. But I am stuck on getting hold of the root certificate.

I've found the following example for accessing a root certificate:

```
NSString *certsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cacert_product" ofType:@"pem"];
NSError *error;
NSString *contentInUTF8 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:certsPath
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:&error];
```

In the example, the resulting `contentInUTF8` can then be used as the certificate parameter to the aforementioned method. But, the resource name in the example, `cacert_product`, seems to be a placeholder; at any rate, I don't have such a resource on my device, and I don't think it would refer to the resource I want to use anyway.

The certificate I want to use is one of the trusted root certificates on [this list](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT207177) of trusted root certificates included with iOS 10. I do not understand how to access it though.

So my question is: how do I get a PEM file for one of the trusted root certificates included on an iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in two parts.

Firstly -- as John Tracid pointed out -- it isn't possible to load a specific root certificate, like I originally wanted to. It looks like the method call that requires a PEM file isn't intended for this use either. It should probably only be used in cases like the one John suggested, namely when you want to add your own certificate which you can then easily access.

Secondly, in order to get gRPC to work, I found this method and comment:

```
/**
 * Configures @c host with TLS/SSL Client Credentials and optionally trusted root Certificate
 * Authorities. If @c pemRootCerts is nil, the default CA Certificates bundled with gRPC will be
 * used.
 */
+ (BOOL)setTLSPEMRootCerts:(nullable NSString *)pemRootCerts
            withPrivateKey:(nullable NSString *)pemPrivateKey
             withCertChain:(nullable NSString *)pemCertChain
                   forHost:(nonnull NSString *)host
                     error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)errorPtr;
```

Specifically: `If @c pemRootCerts is nil, the default CA Certificates bundled with gRPC will be used`. The list of certificates bundled with gRPC is not necessarily the same as the ones bundled with iOS, but it looks like a [pretty solid list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grpc/grpc/master/etc/roots.pem), and the cert I wanted to use is in both.

So in order to get this to work, I just had to pass `nil` for the pem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way for you will be to ask person who issued server certificate for a root certificate in PEM format. They usually have it. And after that you can use it in gRPC.

AFAIK there is no way to get list of root certificates in iOS. When you need to check certificate against iOS root certificates you use policy (like `kSecPolicyAppleSSL`). But you your case you don't have callback for checking server certificate during handshake.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Yes, the issuer has the certificate, and it would be simple to get it. But I am specifically trying not to add any certificates, especially seeing as the root for the server's cert is bundled with iOS. That's kind of the point, in my case. Your answer helped me figure out where to look though. While I didn't have a callback to query certificates against, the service I wanted to use has its own close equivalent; see my answer. Thanks again!